# what are the image sizes of an app for all Android devices

Tags: android

I did a lot search but I didn't get any answer. I am new to android and now I am confused with the background images and splash screen size, I want my app run perfectly on all android device such as from small handset to larger tablet. and I am also confuse with the buttons images. please help me thank I will wait for your kind reply.

Comment: have u tried the below given answer or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have to create different perfect images for different dpi and place them in related drawable folder.Then set this in your xml file:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_iamge.
```

Now Put your background image in all drawable folders,And set it to:

```
xhdpi 960x720
hdpi 640x480
mdpi 470x320
ldpi 320x240
```

Comment: Always  most welcome Jawad..........

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the manual carefully http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thanks bro its v good